# Emojis not rendering

Tags: macos, font, encoding, emoji

My genuine MacOS is not showing emojis. They look just like this:

[image: emojipedia]
[image: character viewer]

None of the following solutions worked for me:

- Creating a new user account
- Restoring Standard Fonts in Font Book
- Booting in Safe Mode
- Changing system font with [macOSLucidaGrande](https://github.com/LumingYin/macOSLucidaGrande)

Comment: Do you have  Macbook with touch bar or what is the model and macOS that you have in your machine atm?

Comment: In Font Book, do you see Apple Color Emoji on the list?  It looks like it may have gone missing, or that you have tried to install a different emoji font.

Comment: I'd bet the emoji font is damaged. Oddly enough if you reinstall your current OS (from an installer or the Command-R interface) right over the top of what you have it should fix that and leave all your data and settings intact, as long as you don't reformat your drive. But make a backup just in case.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I solved it by copying the font file from another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by copying the Apple Color Emoji font from another Mac running the same OS version. You can find it in /System/Library/Fonts.